# hitTestObject() collide somehow not working how it should

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Or that's what I think, at least.

I just began with AS3 and I'm trying to do a little game where one ball moves on its own and the other one is handled by the player. So far, so good. That works.

What isn't working is hitTestObject(); it just returns true when it's like 2 cm from the other object. Here's a picture so you can see: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/37057843/coll2.jpg

I've read that hitTestObject just creats a rectangle around the objects and then tests for collisions on those rectangles, is it because of that?

If you need any piece of code I'll deliver. I know there are some other opensource libraries/engines like Box2D to solve this in a better way, but I don't want to jump to engines directly.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: When doing collision, always consider modelling it yourself. For example, give each actor/object a collision shape, f.e. `Ball.collisionRadius:Number` for an implicit circle. Then do your own collision check, where you check for each pair of `Ball` instances if they are within `ball1.collisionRadius + ball2.collisionRadius` distance of eachother. Future improvements: Limiting the objects to compare using spatial subdivision; different and multiple shapes per object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, hitTestObject will use the clips bounding box.

Check out this link, it has a lot of great information as well as a class that will do what you're looking for

http://sierakowski.eu/list-of-tips/39-collision-detection-methods-hittest-and-hittestobject-alternatives.html

Direct link to the package

http://code.google.com/p/collisiondetectionkit/